# how to remove email footer in odoo?

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, odoo

I need to remove footer from all emails in odoo. I tried to set addons/mail/mail_followers.py footer to "" and signature_company too. But emails still have footer. I restarted ubuntu server, odoo-server but it doesn't help. I use amazon EC2 instance.

Comment: Did you try start odoo server with `-u mail` option to force it to update the module? Also, it would seem much cleaner to create your own module, extend the `mail.notification` model and overwrite the method that way. I can expend this to a full answer if you are interested in that method.

Comment: yes, it would be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an instruction for creating your own module extending `'mail.notification'` model to modify the footer it uses, per your request.

I assume you use odoo 8. For OpenERP 7 the general idea would be the same, but details would be different.

1. Create a new module using the `odoo.py` script:

   ```
   odoo.py scaffold footer_remover addons_dir/
   ```

   (where `footer_remover` is a name of your module and `addons_dir/` is the odoo addons directory)
2. Edit the `footer_remover/__openerp__.py` file. Change the `name` field to set a user friendly name of your module (for example "user2764368's Footer Remover") and add `'mail'` to the list of module dependencies `depends`.
3. Put this in your the `footer_remover/models.py` file:

   ```
   from openerp import models, api

   class FooterlessNotification(models.Model):
       _inherit = 'mail.notification'

       @api.model
       def get_signature_footer(self, user_id, res_model=None, res_id=None, context=None, user_signature=True):
           return ""
   ```

   This will extend the `'mail.notification'` model and replace its `get_signature_footer` method with one that returns an empty footer.
4. Install your module via odoo settings. To find it there you may need to use the "Update Module List" option. If you can't find the option either, you may need to enable the "Technical Features" checkbox in your current user's settings.

Comment: This function don't exist anymore

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to remove the "by Odoo" footer is to enable debug mode and then use the built-in template editor. To do this, add the query parameter `debug` to the site URL, eg:

https://your-odoo-website.com/?debug

Then select "Settings" in the top bar, "General Settings Technical" in the left-hand panel, "Email", "Templates" and select "Notification Email" from the list. Edit this template and remove the whole last line.

Comment: this email template doesn't exist in odoo 13. Any other ideas?

Comment: There's still a view for (in Odoo 14): message_notification_email